# category from url wordpress and keep parent category

Tags: wordpress

I removed the word category in url wordpress by using a custom permalink structure

```
/%category%/%postname%
```

and added `.` in base category

It works but it seems the parent category disappears as well

I would like to have this sructure

```
http://monsite.com/parent_cat/child_cat
```

Could somebody help me with this ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `/%category%/%postname%`, Wordpress will include the category structure in the URL.

Just select the final (child) category as the post category.

As an example, if you have categories

- Book

  - Chapter

    - Page

And you select **page** as the category, the URL will include `.../book/chapter/page/POSTNAME`.

For more customisations, check the [No Category Base (WPML)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/no-category-base-wpml/) plugin.